# Not all Statements are getting added in Esper runtime V8.5

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, esper

Our current application runs on Esper V5.2 but while upgrading to V8.5 facing the below issue -

We have total 6 nodes(VM). While starting the servers few statements are not at all loading in any of the VMs and few statements are loading in 2-3 VMs out of all 6 nodes. And this is all random.

Also, we have an option to edit the statements at runtime. Upon editing we first remove the statements from the runtime and add again the new one. The above statements which didn't load at the start up are getting added this time(In case of editing functionality).

Everything is working fine in older version i.e. V5.2

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a bug in your application code around tracking deployments. Between version 5.2 and 8.5 there are changes in Esper architecture moving Esper to become an EPL compiler spitting out JVM byte code and to an EPL runtime loading byte code only. Your application code that manages the compile-deploy steps and how it decides what to deploy where needs to be checked as this is done outside of Esper core and is done by your application.

Comment: If the deployment id is unique for each statement and statement name is same for all statements, is it fine? or statement name also should be unique?

Comment: We have used the compileDeploy method from http://www.espertech.com/2018/10/23/esper-8-migrating-step-by-step-for-existing-applications/ and added below Deploymentoption -  
options.setDeploymentId(deploymentId + subscription.getId().toString());
options.setStatementNameRuntime(new StatementNameRuntimeOption() {
public String getStatementName(StatementNameRuntimeContext env) {return "DEFAULT_STATEMENT_NAME";}});options.setStatementUserObjectRuntime(new StatementUserObjectRuntimeOption() {public Object getUserObject(StatementUserObjectRuntimeContext env) {return subscription;}})